# Understanding the notation of the gradient of a vector function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

In my finite element method book, there is a notation which is confusing me.  Given $v:R^2\rightarrow R^2$, I'm supposed to evaluate

$\sigma\cdot \nabla v^T$
where $\sigma$ is a smooth tensor valued function.  What is confusing me is the notation $\nabla v^T$.  How do I interpret the gradient of a vector?  Is it a matrix or a vector?  Also, should I interpret the equation as $\nabla (v^T)$ or $\nabla^T v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of a vector field is

$$
(\nabla v)_{ij} = \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}
$$

and so

$$
\sigma\cdot\nabla v^T=\sigma\cdot(\nabla v)^T=\sum_{i,j=1}^3\sigma_{ij}\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}
$$

(given that $A\cdot B=\sum_{ij}A_{ij}B_{ji}$ and so $A\cdot B^T=\sum_{ij}A_{ij}B_{ij}$)

Comment: So the gradient of a vector is a matrix then, right?

Comment: Yes, it is a matrix. The gradient raises by one the order of the *object* to which it is applied: a gradient of a scalar field is a vector field; the gradient of a vector field is a double tensor field, and so on.

Comment: According to the book, the final result $\sigma\cdot\nabla v^T$ is supposed to be a scalar quantity.  Your final result seems to be a vector, if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: No, you sum on both indexes, so the resulting dot product is a scalar.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you, @enzotib! :)

Comment: So then, $\nabla v$ is equivalent to the jacobian of v!  That's cool!

Comment: Is the product in the notation $A\cdot B$ called a "tensor product" or a "tensor dot product"?  Is there a special name for this product?

Comment: It is a inner product in the vector space of tensors, don't know the name in English.